# Converting JSON into readable format

Tags: javascript, php, html, api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0T0X3.png)

I am trying to put the data in this array, into a readable format for my data tables. I have no clue how i'd solve this one. Any help is appreciated.

The only part of the array I want is the 'message' row.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you skipped a few or more tutorials, but it's done like this:

```
$data = json_decode($yourJsonString, true);
var_dump($data['message']);
```